# Riddle: Best caller

Tags: optimization, puzzle

Assume we have an closed interval $I = [a,b]$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_+$ ($a,b\geq0$).
Three persons pick a number each in the interval, lets call the numbers $A$, $B$ and $C$.

We then look at 1/3rd of the average of the numbers. So $M = (A+B+C)/9$. If your bet is closest to $M$, you win the amount of money you bet.

In case of a tie (where the tie is the closest to $M$) then the participants will draw who wins. This essentially divides the price in two or three so ties are to be avoided.

**Assume that you know the numbers $A$ and $B$, how should you pick $C$ in order to be closest, *and* win the most amount of money?**

Note you can always bet $C = (A+B)/8$, to ble closest. But this will rarely make the most money. Say the interval is $[0,100]$, $A=1$ and $B=50$. Then you can bet $C=51/8 \approx 6.375$ and win. Since $M = (6.375+1+50)/9 = 6.375$. However you can also bet $C = 13.2857$, which makes you win more.

Comment: You can't always bet $(A+B)/8$, since it might not be in $[a,b]$.

Comment: What happens in the event of a tie?

Comment: Lets say there is a coin flip or a draw.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that $0\le A\le B$.  Our main competitor is now $A$, for any sensible bid.  We tie with  $A$ if $$\left|\frac{1}{9}(A+B+C)-A\right|=\left|\frac{1}{9}(A+B+C)-C\right|$$
or $$B+C-8A=\pm(A+B-8C)$$
In the case of $+$, we have $C=A$, and in the case of $-$ we have $C=\frac{2}{7}B-A$.

These two options form an interval, on the interior of which $C$ wins.  We want to pick the largest $C$ strictly inside this interval (to avoid sharing the prize with $A$) that is still inside $[a,b]$.

Comment: Given A=50, B=1, then your interval becomes (-49.71,50) which seems rather poor..

Comment: That does not satisfy my condition of $0\le A\le B$.  You should relabel as $A=1, B=50$, to get $(1,13.28)$.